# ODBC driver - IgnoreTransactions advanced option

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc, simba

According to the release notes, the IgnoreTransactions advanced option was added to the ODBC driver in 2.1.16.

We found documentation here:

https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/linux/content/odbc/bq/options/noui/ignoretransactions.htm

but it is missing from the list of advanced options in the documentation, and in our testing, it does not appear to work (at least with the Windows ODBC driver v2.1.17).

Does anyone know the story about this option?  Is it fully implemented and available in the Windows ODBC driver?  Any caveats/suggestions?

Comment: Any update on this?  Is there a way to contact Simba directly about this?

Comment: Still hoping to hear whether this is a known issue.